# MLPClassifier threshold factor to eliminate test samples that are not in match with train data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am using MLPClassifer example from
[scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html#classification)

The code for training:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
X = [[0., 0.], [1., 1.]]
y = [0, 1]
clf = MLPClassifier(solver='lbfgs', alpha=1e-5,
                    hidden_layer_sizes=(5, 2), random_state=1)

clf.fit(X, y)
```

At the predict step, we use test data [2., 2.], [-1., -2.] in
`clf.predict([[2., 2.], [-1., -2.]])`. The output of this function is
`array([1, 0])`

As we observe, the test data [2.,2.] is not in the train dataset we passed. Still, we got the closest match as label 1.

What i am trying to find is if the test data i supplied is not in the train dataset, i should print a message to user that data is not valid instead of telling him the wrong label as 1.

For instance, in knn classification, i have [kneighbours function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.kneighbors) which tells the distance of my closest neighbours to the test data i supplied in a 0 to 1 scale. So, i could easily eliminate the test data samples who are highly distant from my train data samples by keeping threshold at 0.6 or 0.7.

Is there any criteria/threshold like this i could do with MLPClassifier or with any one of [Incremental Classifiers mentioned here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/scaling_strategies.html#incremental-learning) which can restrict my test samples if not present in train dataset ?

Comment: So, you want to predict samples from only training set?

Comment: Sorry, but that's not how these models work. It is assumed that the train and test samples are independently and identically distributed based on some unknown distribution, and the MLP is only learning this distribution. If you are stuffing invalid inputs down its throat, you shouldn't expect it to know because it assumes you know what you're doing. I would recommend you filter those invalid values out in advance before passing it to predict.

Comment: @user1 , Then, can't you just check if the sample is in the training set and if so just report corresponding y value?. What is the point of using a classifier?

Comment: I have a train dataset that is classifying 10 different face images of mine. When i predict my new face image, it always predict as mine. Perfect. No problem,. However, When i give my colleague image which is not trained, still it is matching to one of my trained face. My face shouldnot match with my colleague face even though there is little similarity.

Comment: I tried this with knn classifier and threshold factor is working fine there because of kneighbour function. However, i want to see how i could predict this with other classfiers. I am curious to know if there is any distance formula or probabilities that i could set as filter. i tried to find some way with predict_proba(test_data) and got values as [[0.34 0.002...]. Am not sure if this could be something i should concentrate on.

Comment: @user1, what did you pass as a train data set to your model? Did you pass different people's faces including yours?

Comment: No, i just passed mine. Train folder with 10 different faces of mine.

Comment: @user1, it doesn't make much sense to me... It's not even a binary (2) classification [your face or not], it's a "unary" (1) classification [your face] which will always give you the same class ;-)

Comment: @MaxU, If i do the same thing with knn_classifier, kneighbours tells me the new test image is how far from my face images. So, depending on the distance, i set threshold. Any face with distance >0.5 is not a good match. So, i neglect those images. However, i am not sure if i could do something similar like this with MLP or other incremental classifiers.

Comment: Is it beacuse SGD, MLP, MUltinominalNB, BernoulianNB all are linear classifier whereas knn is non linear ? Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: I don't think your KNN Classifier will work well either... For the supervised learning algorithms we should train our models to distinguish between different classes. You have trained your model with a single class only. So it doesn't know anything about different classes (NOT your face) - even that they might exist...

Comment: @MaxU, ok. Now, I have added faces of three more diffrerent persons and trained.  Now i want to test with some new unknown 4th person. At this point, i want to have a control that instead of algorithm matchíng this 4th person to the closest featres of any one of 3 trained persons.

Comment: @user1, in this case i think you should train your model using pictures of 4 known persons and lots of pictures of __unknown__ persons, so you will have altogether 5 classes: `[person1, person2, person3, person4, unknown]` ...

Comment: ok. i am actually working on fraud detection. I cannot know the unknown persons to train their faces. Atleast, i cannot train till the first time i capture their face. If i couldnot distinguish the trained dataset of people from unknown users, its of no use.

Answer (score 0):

In comments you have explained that you've trained your classifier with a single class (picture of *your* face). In order to be able to classify whether it's your face or not you should train your model with the negative class (**not** your face) as well, so the model will learn characteristics that might help to identify **your** face among different people.

The internet is full of pictures with faces, so you can easily gather a few thousand such pictures and train your classifier properly.

Comment: I extended in the comments later that i trained now over 4 different classes. My problem is not the classifaction. Algorithm classify perfectly with whatever data i am passing. However, even for unknown data, it is giving a closest match. I want to avoid this. It is possible with knn classifier to filter out the unknown faces which are not at all trained even once with the distance measure. In 0 to1 scale, All my faces have distances from 0 to 0.1 or so. Anything above 0.5 is highly propable that it is not my face. I am lookng for something similar like this measure with MLP

Comment: Eventhough i take all the faces of pictures available in internet for classification, new faces still add up. I think however good the classfier model is, having a threshold can give much control.

Comment: @user1, try to ask this question [on datascience.stackexchange.com](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: ok. thank you. feel free to add any of your ideas/suggestions

Comment: Question migrated to https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/28758/mlpclassifier-threshold-factor-to-eliminate-test-samples-that-are-not-in-match-w.

Answer (score 0):

[Decision function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.decision_function) : https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/28762/15884. It holds positive, 0 and negative values. Hence setting threshold above 0 can work in eliminating outliers.

EDIT: If you are using partial_fit(), the threshold factor has to be checked again. Threshold above 0 works only for fit(). Also, MLPClassifier doesnot have decision_function(). This answer is meant for algorithms that provide decision_function().